# jQuery equalize heights script only works if the first element is the highest?

Tags: jquery

so I have tow chunks of JS running in two separate files. The first passes in a list of elements, the second takes those elements and finds whichever is the highest and applies that height to the rest. A fairly basic script really, but I've messed up somewhere. The script works like a charm as long as the first element it comes across is the highest. If it's the second then it applies the height of the second elements across all of them...

Can someone sanity check what I've done and advise where I've gone wrong?

The two scripts:

```
function equalizeFunction1(){
    var elements = [
        $('.element1'), 
        $('#element2')
    ]; 
    masterEqualizeHeights(elements);
}
```

The brains behind the operation:

```
function masterEqualizeHeights(arg){
    elements = arg;
    var maxHeight = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].height() > maxHeight){maxHeight = elements[i].height()}
    }
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].height(maxHeight)
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't that what you desire? to apply the highest height to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you have designed the array, you array has jQuery object which might contain more than 1 element, so in the for loop you need to iterate over each element in the jquery object and check the height else only the height of the first element in the set will be considered

In your array since the class selector can return more than 1 element, you need to iterate over each item in that jQuery object so

```
function masterEqualizeHeights(arg) {
    var elements = arg;
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $.each(elements, function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            var height = $(this).height();
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
        });
    });
    $.each(elements, function () {
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    })
}
```

---

A more simpler approach will be

```
function equalizeFunction1() {
    masterEqualizeHeights($('.element1, #element2'));
}


function masterEqualizeHeights(els) {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    els.each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = elements[i].height()
        }
    });
    els.height(maxHeight)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, to test I have swapped out the existing masterEqualizeHeights function with your first one, and it works, however I've spotted a further issue. Let's say I define to separate elements to compare, such as:

`function equalizeFunction1(){
 var elements = [
  $('#text-6 h2'),
  $('#text-2 h2')
 ]; 
    masterEqualizeHeights(elements);
}` - that works. But If I want to simplify it and just test all h2 like this: `function equalizeFunction1(){
 var elements = [
  $('h2')
 ]; 
    masterEqualizeHeights(elements);
}` it doesn't work any more...

Comment: are you trying the first approach or second one